# Adding google account to my website in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a job portal website project in that i need to signup user by using google open authentication .. so that i can retrieve his/her account details like firstname,lastname,emailid, mobile number etc .. 
similarly fot yahoo also in asp.net.

Comment: All the information you required must be supplied by the user.  What you can do is handle the user authentication by using OAuth 2.0.  I suggest you only collect the information required for a basic profile all the user to supply what they want to supply.

Comment: ok i will take a basic information like fname,lname and emailid

Comment: @Jav_Rock its ok you can close vote this question up others may see this and repeat this question.. please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check **[DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/)**. It is a .NET library to integrate google/yahooo/open ID login support to your .NET applications.

**This is how it works.**

You show the Different login options in your website(google/ yahoo etc) and when user clicks on that they will be redirected to these providers login page. you will be passing the url of one of your page (something like a callback !) so that after successfully authenticated, the provided will redirect to this purticular page our yours.  You will not get the password of user. You will be getting an OpenID string corresponding to the account. You may need to store this in your UserInfo table so that next time when the user visits, after authentication, you can bring user related stuff(profile preference etc...)

I do not think you will be able to retrieve the mobile number of the user. You can get the EmailID of the user.

there are lots of examples in the internet out there.

http://midnightprogrammer.net/post/Add-Google-Login-Support-In-ASPNET-With-OAuth.aspx

http://danhounshell.com/blog/adding-openid-to-your-web-site-in-conjunction-with-asp-net-membership/

Comment: but i cant installing dotnetauthopenID there is no library package mangaer in my visula studio 2010.. and i am using developer version please help me

Comment: you dont need to install. Just add the DLL in to your reference section.